# Extract data from several netcdf files using ncks in for loop

Tags: linux, bash, netcdf, nco

I am trying to extract certain variables from netcdf files. 
The following code works if I apply it to a single file:

```
ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 20091208000001.nc testU.nc
```

See also question: [Hyperslab of a 4D netcdf variable using ncks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54367298/hyperslab-of-a-4d-netcdf-variable-using-ncks) for explanation.
Now I want to use this code on several .nc files with following names:

```
20091208000001.nc
20091208000002.nc
20091208000003.nc
```

I tried the following loop:

```
# !bin/bash
for ((x=1;x<=3;x+=1))
do
ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 2009120800000$x.nc testU.nc
done
```

I get the error

```
ncks: ERROR received 4 filenames; need no more than two
```

**How do I get the loop to only extract from one file at a time and then append the extracted output from all the files into a single output file?**

Comment: For every loop iteration, each of the files from 20091208000001.nc to ..3.nc is processed. So it basically is one file at a time. What is wrong with this

Comment: I don't know it should work. That's why I posted it. I get this error 4 times in my output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the words `ni_u,234,235,1` were mistaken as another filename. You would need another `-d` before that.

And if you are processing multiple nc files, you might want to rename `testU.nc` so that they don't overlap, or you could use `ncrcat` to concatenate into one single file. E.g.

```
ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 -d ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 2009120800000?.nc testU.nc
```

Comment: If this was the reason (which makes sense, BTW), then the claim made in the question that the code works fine out of the loop would be false :-(

Comment: @Poshi yes, I know, it worked fine the day before, I did not see the -d was missing.  Lesson learned ...

Comment: That's the reason I was asking you to rerun the command, and me writing the exact command you had to test, for you to just cut and paste and check the statement was true. BTW, it would be nice to correct the question so the answer makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple errors in your script, but nothing that could lead to your actual error.

- The shebang line should not contain space and the path should be absolute
- There's a comma in the `for` condition that should be a semicolon

  ```
  #!/bin/bash

  for ((x=1;x<=3;x+=1))
  do
      ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 2009120800000$x.nc testU.nc
  done
  ```

When I prepend `echo` to the command you want to run, I get this result:

```
ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 20091208000001.nc testU.nc
ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 20091208000002.nc testU.nc
ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 20091208000003.nc testU.nc
```

Three invocations with a single file each. That code is working. It looks like there's something else. Are you simplifying your code or showing us the full code?

Comment: I corrected the mistakes, still the same error. I use bash namescript.sh to run it.

Comment: @Jellyse I updated my answer with the result I'm obtaining.

Comment: This is litteraly my complete code in the file testing.sh The folder only has those three files and the testing.sh file. Is it possible the nco is not correctly installed?

Comment: Ok I reinstalled it, still the same error. The only thing I can think of is that somewhere on my computer there is another file with the same name and that's why it's confused.

Comment: @Jellyse, prepend `echo` to your command (`echo ncks -C......`) and check the output. Having other files with the same name in the computer should not cause this error.

Comment: I get the exact same thing as you when I do echo ncks ... (no errors) but the file testU.nc does not get created.

Comment: No, with the `echo` you are getting the command that will be executed, but it is not executed, so no creation fo the result. If you are getting the same output than me, it means that it is being generated properly. What happens when you run one of this commands alone? Try just running `ncks -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 20091208000001.nc testU.nc`. Did you get the same error message?

Comment: it works just fine when I do that. Nicely have my testU.nc with the data I need. Thank you for helping me btw.

Comment: This does not make sense. There should be no difference between running the command yourself or letting the loop run it for you. It is the same command. Last thing I cant advise is that you `set -x` before the loop, run it, and check carefully the debug output. The behaviour you describe cannot be reproduced and conceptually does not make sense either :-/

Answer (score 1):

@Packard is right on both counts. Moreover, the stride of 1 is default and thus not needed. Hence

ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,151,152 -d ni_u,234,235 -v vel_u 2009120800000${x}.nc testU${x}.nc

Answer (score 0):

I edited the code above according to the dimensions I wanted (lat, lon)

```
ncrcat -C -F -d nj_u,151,152,1 -d ni_u,234,235,1 -v vel_u 2009120800000?.nc testU.nc
```

and the feedback was this:

> HINT: If operation fails, try multislabbing
>   (http://nco.sf.net/nco.html#msa) wrapped dimension using ncks first,
>   and then apply ncrcat to the resulting file